# $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=3z_0^2$ if $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be the vertices of an equilateral triangle and $z_0$ be the circumcentre

Tags: complex-numbers, triangles, centroid

> Prove that, if $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be the vertices of an equilateral triangle and $z_0$ be the circumcentre, then $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=3z_0^2$

**My Attempt**
$$
z_0=\frac{z_1+z_2+z_3}{3}\implies 3z_0=z_1+z_2+z_3\\
9z_0^2=z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2+2z_1z_2+2z_2z_3+2z_3z_1
$$

How do I proceed further and complete the proof ?

Comment: $$\sqrt3=\dfrac{z_1-z_0}{z_0-z_2}$$

Squaring we get $$3(z_0-z_2)^2=(z_1-z_0)^2\iff?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we clearly know (by rotation theorem):
$$\frac{z_2-z_0}{z_1-z_0} = \frac{z_3-z_0}{z_2-z_0} = \frac{z_1-z_0}{z_3-z_0}$$

On Solving you'll get:
$$z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2 = z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1$$

Further, we know:
$$(z_1-z_0)+(z_2-z_0)+(z_3-z_0) = 0$$

Transferring terms and squaring both sides we get (after using the prev. result):
$$3(z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2) = 9z_0^2$$

Or, we get:
$$z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2= 3z_0^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$z_1=z_0+r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta),$$  $$z_2=z_0+r(\cos(120^{\circ}+\theta)+i\sin(120^{\circ}+\theta))$$ and $$z_3=z_0+r(\cos(240^{\circ}+\theta)+i\sin(240^{\circ}+\theta)).$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$\cos2\theta+\cos(240^{\circ}+2\theta)+\cos(480^{\circ}+2\theta)=0,$$
$$\sin2\theta+\sin(240^{\circ}+2\theta)+\sin(480^{\circ}+2\theta)=0,$$
$$\cos\theta+\cos(120^{\circ}+\theta)+\cos(240^{\circ}+\theta)=0$$ and
$$\sin\theta+\sin(120^{\circ}+\theta)+\sin(240^{\circ}+\theta)=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: "Let $z_0=0$" it deserves an explanation why you can assume that. The equation is not invariant under translations.

Comment: @Wojowu We can write $z_1=z_0+r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ and similar and we'll get the same computations. If you wish a can fix my post, but I think it's the same.

Comment: I disagree that they are the same computations. Similar - perhaps, but not identical.

Comment: @Wojowu I added something. See now.